# Maclaurin series of: $ f(x) = {x + 5\over1-x^2}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to get the Maclauren series of:
$ f(x) = {x + 5\over1-x^2}$.

I am sure there is some trick here, the result according to Mathematica is:

$5 + x + 5x^2 + x^3 + 5x^4 + x^5 + 5x^6 + \ ...$

I defined:

$f^n_m = {x^n\over(1-x^2)^m}$

$f^n_m = 0$ for $n < 0 $ (just a definition necessary to make the next formula work for $n = 0$)

I've computed:

$(f^n_m)' = nf^{n-1}_m + 2mf^{n+1}_{m+1}$.

We have $f(x) = f^1_1(x) + 5f^0_1(x)$

I tried going from here, I didn't try induction as I want to see how I could get this result without assuming it first.

If I keep taking derivatives I get more and more terms of the form $f^s_r$.

But didn't find the pattern, I can see in the Mclauren series we evaluate the derivatives at 0 and thus only terms of the form $f^0_r$ contribute.

I tried also to just take some derivatives brute force and looking at the result, but they just keep getting more and more terms and I cannot ignore any of them because eventually as I differentiate they will all contribute at some point to the evaluation at 0.

Any advice will be helpful but I would like to see how I could have arrived at the result, so proving it by induction if it assumes the result won't be of much help.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice we all know the following

$$ \sum^{\infty} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x} $$

for $|x| < 1 $. Now, applying this

$$ \frac{1}{1 - x^2} = \sum x^{2n} \implies\frac{x+5}{1-x^2} = (x+5) \sum x^{2n} = \sum x^{2n + 1} + \sum 5x^{2n} =$$

$$ = 5 + x + 5x^2 + x^3 + 5x^4 + x^5 + 5x^6 + \ ... $$

Comment: Haha, thank you, classic case of overthinking, need to be more open minded and try different methods!

Answer (score 2):

I think you make the problem more difficult than it is. Perform the division of 1 by (1 - x^2). As a result, you have 1 + x^2 + x^4 + x^6 + ... + x^(2n). Now, multiply by (x+5) and expand. You will get what Mathematica told you. Easy, isn't ?

Comment: Yes it is! definitely taught me that if I should try a wider variety of methods!